# New Connections are not accepting by Restlet Server

Tags: java, restlet-2.0

I am using Restlet to implement a web service. From the PHP Client making many consecutive calls to the server, but after a small number of calls complete successfully, further calls hang the server, which shows the message:

```
INFO: Worker service state: Full 
Jun 22, 2015 2:38:31 PM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper$1 rejectedExecution
INFO: Worker service tasks: 0 queued, 10 active, 16 completed, 26 scheduled.
Jun 22, 2015 2:38:31 PM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper$1 rejectedExecution
INFO: Worker service thread pool: 1 core size, 10 largest size, 10 maximum size, 10 current size
Jun 22, 2015 2:38:31 PM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller run
INFO: Stop accepting new connections and transactions. Consider increasing the maximum number of threads.
```

Please find below the restlet server component code base:

```
    final Component serverComponent = new Component();
    serverComponent.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);
    final Series<Parameter> parameters = serverComponent.getContext().getParameters();
    parameters.add("maxThreads", "150");
    parameters.add("minThreads", "10");
    parameters.add("lowThreads", "145");
    parameters.add("maxQueued", "20");
    parameters.add("maxTotalConnections", "10000");
    serverComponent.getDefaultHost().attach("/v1", new Appv1());
    try {
        serverComponent.start();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        LOGGERS.error("Exception while starting the application: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Can anybody know what changes I have missed in the setup ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the jetty extension of the framework, instead of the internal connector.
If you want to do so, just add the org.restlet.ext.jetty.jar and org.eclipse.jetty.jar to your classpath.